# Bold items in a string based on 1 or more matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
str = "Hello world. Today is Wednesday"
matchedTerms
```

matchedTerms contains data like so:

```
> "world"
> "word, is"
```

What I would like to do is update the str like so:

```
"Hello <b>world</b>. Today <b>is</b> Wednesday"
```

What would be the right way in Ruby/Rails to update the string given matchedTerms?

Comment: I've been trying

`matchedTerms.each do |term|
    str.gsub(/term/, "<b>#{term}</b>")
end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) method takes a block which can make this pretty easy (and should be more efficient than writing an iterator/loop).

Here's how I'd go about this:

```
matched_terms = ["world", "is"]
pattern = Regexp.new(matched_terms.join("|"), Regexp::IGNORECASE)

str = "Hello world. Today is Wednesday"
result = str.gsub(pattern) { |match| "<b>#{match}</b>" }
# => "Hello <b>world</b>. Today <b>is</b> Wednesday"
```

I couldn't understand why you had `"word, is"` as one of your matchedTerms given your example output... so I just simplified it to `"is"`. If you really wanted `"word, is"` to be considered as 2 additional terms to match on -- `"word"` and `"is"` -- then I'd clean that up ahead of time, like this:

```
matched_terms.map! { |mt| mt.split(", ") }.flatten!
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make this case-insensative?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've updated the answer to make the regular expression case-insensitive. I just added the `Regexp::IGNORECASE` option to the `Regexp.new` call. (Also, I fixed my typo: used to say `Regex.new` but should've been `Regexp.new`.)

Comment: if a matched term is @cnn for example it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the code and result that's not working? Because it's working for me. `r = Regexp.new('asdf|@cnn', Regexp::IGNORECASE)` then `"ASDF asdf @cnn".gsub(r) { "hi" } # => "hi hi hi"`.

Comment: You do need to keep in mind that the matched terms need to respect regex rules, or be converted to respect them. That is, `pattern` is a Regular expression that's constructed from a string. So the string has to be a valid regular expression still.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for every pattern you want. But this will return what you want above.

```
str = "Hello world. Today is Wednesday"
puts str
matchedTerms = ["world", "word, is"]
matchedTerms.each do |term|
  split = term.split
  split.each do |word|
    # case insensitive : str.gsub!(/#{word}/i, "<b>#{word}</b>")
    str.gsub!(word, "<b>#{word}</b>")
  end
end

puts str

>> Hello world. Today is Wednesday
>> Hello <b>world</b>. Today <b>is</b> Wednesday
```

Comment: Thanks, is this case insensitive?

Comment: Maybe a regex is the way to go?

Comment: `str.gsub!(/#{word}/i, "<b>#{word}</b>")` this will work in case insensitive way.